# Mini-Markdown is not working in comments

Tags: support

My Mini-Markdown is not working in comments for [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999458/desktop-link-will-be-broken-after-restart#999458), but here everything is fine.

I tried:

- `[link](http://...)`
- and `code`

Comment: Probably spaces - in your first comment there's a space between ] and ( in the link markdown.

Comment: @muru: That's not a comment; that's an answer! **:-)**

Comment: At about the code `c:\`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As muru says in [their comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17631/mini-markdown-is-not-working-in-comments/17642#comment36802_17631), the problem is that your Markdown code has some issues.

- `[EndOfLife] (ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)`

  In this part, there's a space between `]` and `(` which breaks the markdown code.
- `` `E:` ``

  In this part, I assume you have typed the following in your comment: `` `E:\` ``. The backslash at the end is being treated as an escape character. This is making the code break (in answers, your markdown code would work just fine).
  What you need to write for it to work is ``` ``E:\`` ```. The output of this would have been what you needed: `E:\`.

  This tells the markdown engine that you are using double backticks for code formatting, and not one. So the backtick is not being escaped.

Comment: Ah, that's what's wrong with the code formatting

Comment: @muru Yeah, it's odd that the backticks & escape characters are processed differently in comments and answers. I've been trying them out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/306393#306393). The results are strange.